# Facing issue in removing item from custom list adapter ListActivity

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, listactivity, listadapter

I am using list activity to display data with custom list adapter with checkbox. When user selects items with checkbox, a button appears in bottom which is then clicked to delete items. When user selects one item and deletes then data in the list is working correctly. But when user selects more than one items then only one item gets deleted but the second one remains checked. Can any one please point out what can be the issue? I post here the getView() metthod of custom adapter, onCheckedChangeListener and code for removal of items. Please help accordingly.

```
<code>Custom List Adapter
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if(view == null) 
        {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.gmail_list_layout, null);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.checkView = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
            viewHolder.timeView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time_content);
            viewHolder.fromView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.from_content);
            viewHolder.subjectView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.subject_content);
            viewHolder.rootLayout = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.rootGmail);

            view.setTag(viewHolder);


        }
        else
        {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            Log.i("mustang", "Items have been removed though.");
        }

        MailMessage msg = emails.get(position);

        viewHolder.checkView.setChecked(false);
        viewHolder.checkView.setTag(position);
        viewHolder.checkView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkListener);

        viewHolder.fromView.setText(msg.getFromArray().get(0));
        viewHolder.subjectView.setText(msg.getSubject());
        viewHolder.timeView.setText(msg.getReceivedDate());

        if(!msg.getIsSeen())
        {
            viewHolder.rootLayout.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        }

        return view;

    }

    OnCheckedChangeListener checkListener = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            Integer position = (Integer)buttonView.getTag();
            Log.i("mustang", "Position: " + position);
            MailMessage message = emails.get(position);
            if(isChecked)
            {
                checkedPositions.add(position);
                buttons.put(position, buttonView);
            }
            else
            {
                checkedPositions.remove(position);
                buttons.remove(position);
            }

            Log.i("mustang", "Positions Array: " + checkedPositions.size());

            context.itemsSelected(checkedPositions);    
        }
    };
```

Code for removal of items when the button is clicked :

`private OnClickListener deleteItemsListener = new OnClickListener() {`

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ArrayList<Integer> positions = emails.getCheckedPositions();
            for(int p : positions)
            {
                messges.remove(p);
            }
            emails.notifyDataSetChanged();
            emails.clearList();

            deleteItems.setText("");
            deleteItems.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
}
}
</code>
```

Here emails is the custom adapter and messges is the list used in adapter.  Please help me sort out the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: post your emails.getCheckedPositions(); code also

Comment: it is just returning the arraylist of positions which is being built in onCheckedChangeListener, function is public ArrayList<Integer> getCheckedPositions()
 {
  return checkedPositions;
 }